# How to install cynogenmod on Moto E?

Tags: cyanogenmod, rooting

I have Moto E with android 5.1.

I like install cynogenmod. What are the steps I need to follow?

Comment: https://wiki.cyanogenmod.org/w/Install_CM_for_condor

Comment: @firelord Can't it get easier than that? I have seen that before.

Comment: I see. So, what's hard to follow there? Also, what other guides/tutorials have you been through already? Tell us what precisely you find difficult in them?

Comment: That came up when I googled. It seemed complicated. I asked the question here.

Comment: @firelord Can you tell me what I need to have and know in order to follow the procedure? I will try to follow the procedure. I am afraid of bricking my phone.

Answer (score 0):

Go on to [Latest Cyanogenmod for Moto E](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/condor-latest.zip/)
Go on to [Latest Cyanogenmod Recovery](http://download.cyanogenmod.org/get/condor-latest-recovery.img)

Wipe Dalvik Cache while changing the OS, NO NEED FOR Factory Reset
Take backup of important system apps as they get lost after installing any other ROM.
IMPORTANT: TAKE BACKUP OF YOUR CURRENT OS BEFORE CHANGING OS.
YOU DO NEED 5-6 GB FOR BACKUP(NANDROID BACKUP).
YOU NEED A ROOTED DEVICE.
YOU NEED PATIENCE. all done!